# How to use/link "esc" key to web pages?

Tags: modal-dialog, key-events

A window/popup in web page can be provided with close (X) button at top-right corner to close that. How to make one closed with 'escape' key pressed?

Facebook chat boxes will be closed with the "esc" key pressed. How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Which *window/popup in web page* are you using?

Comment: Im asking in general !!!

Comment: It totally depends, which dialog/popup you are using, if are you using jquery dialog then you can close it on `keyCode`, but nothing like in general, **be specific**.

Comment: Then the answer is "using escape keyCode" . Thanq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally depends on which window dialog/popup are you using. Because different dialog/popup can be handled by differently.

But you can use *keyboard key press event*(key code :`27`) to detect when use clicked `ESC` key.

Here is the example:

Suppose, you're using jquery dialog to show your content then you can handle `ESC` key event.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // ESCAPE key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!